# after preg_match_all, how to get the value if it is in another row

Tags: php, mysql

My mission is to get the desired date when a specific word is mention. I want the date when for exampel "spelmissbruk" is mention, so i would want the 29/7/2014, and that is working as i want.

```
22/10/2013 ånger, ska bet 6,428:-, 
bet 6428, 2109+2016+2303 inlagt
23/5/2014 bl 26/5, medd inga avgifter) 
29/7/2014 spelmissbruk 
29/12/2014 föreslår godkänn
27/4/2016 Föreslår godkänn
```

My problem is that in some cases the date can be in another row.

```
spelmissbruk 
29/7/2014
```

This is code im using now to extract the desired date. Any tips would be appreciated.

```
  $subject = $row['anteckning'];


$pattern = $wordToFind;
        if(preg_match_all("/(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}).*$pattern.*/i",$subject, $matches))  {

            $date = $matches[1][0];

        }
```

Below is an example of a date that will not be saved as i want

```
            12/7/2018 -  kund ringer in, har fått hem fakturan men känner ej igen den. Kund uppger att det ej är han som tagit lånet. Kund har ej fått hem andra fakturor eller någon kreditupplysning. Swedbank hade hört av sig till kund och meddela tom ett belopp på 15000:- som hade kommit in på hans konto och sedan förts iväg igen till okänt konto. Meddelat att ansökan är identifierad.
Bett kund tag kontakt med sin bank, bisnode, polisanmälan och skicka polisanmälan till oss.
```

This is what i have tried to do

```
 $move_date = preg_replace("(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4})", "-", $subject)

$explodeDate = explode("-",$move_date);
        print_r($explodeDate);
```

My idéa is to explode it and some how remove all the rows.

Here i have an example text when a date will not be saved, it is because of the rowformating. What im searching for is the word "polis" and if it is a match stop and get the date.

```
12/7/2018 - Sofi: kund ringer in, har fått hem fakturan men känner ej igen den. Kund uppger att det ej är han som tagit lånet. Kund har ej fått hem andra fakturor eller någon kreditupplysning. Swedbank hade hört av sig till kund och meddela tom ett belopp på 15000:- som hade kommit in på hans konto och sedan förts iväg igen till okänt konto. Meddelat att ansökan är identifierad.
Bett kund tag kontakt med sin bank, bisnode, polisanmälan och skicka polisanmälan till oss.
```

here is a text that will save the date as i want

```
25/7/2018 - Sofi: detta är bedrägeri, kund son hade gjort bedrägeri på kund, kund har polisanmält, spärrat sin bankdosa osv. Pengarna finns kvar på kunds konto, även ifrån andra bolag. Meddelat 25000:-, därefter slutbetalt. Kund betalar detta idag. Lagt in spärr på kunds begäran
```

Comment: The date being on the next line would not be that much of a problem - if it wasn’t _in front of_ the search term in the other case. Can you at least guarantee that it will always be either one of those formats - either date and keyword on the same line, in that order, or keyword on its own on one line, date on its own on the next …?

Comment: Please see my edited answer, i hope it's more clear.

Comment: Not really. First of all, which particular word/phrase are you looking for in that now? Secondly, what is the actual problem - that it doesn’t find a match at all, or that the found match does not include the second line? And what determines that this second line belongs to the match you are looking for, but not the next (potential) third line coming after this? Would that start with a date again and therefor mark the beginning of the next “record”, or …?

Comment: The script works as following, if i search for a word "polis" if it find's a match then stop and get the date from that match. And the problem is that sometimes, i wont get the date beacuse of the row formating in the text

Comment: That’s because `.` matches everything _but_ newline characters, if you want it to match those as well, you need to add the `s` modifier.

Comment: I have tried to add s modifier, it wont work either.

Comment: @J.Doe1989, check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to use the `s` modifier so that the`.` symbol searches for a multi-line match. Secondly, don’t use `.*` because in your case it will always match only the first date. Third, use `preg_quote` to quote special characters from the string you want to find.

As a complete example, try this one:

```
// To avoid errors or unexpected results, we must escape regex characters
// For example, without this we cannot find some punctuation marks
$search = preg_quote('polis', '#');

// A simple regular expression to find the date
// Since we have to use it twice, we do not repeat ourselves
$date_rgxp = '\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}';

// Now it’s time to capture our date, for this we are using a more complex regex
// - Use "#" as delimiter, as it will allow do not escape "/" from the $date_rgxp
// - Use a named group to capture the date (it can be written as "($date_rgxp)", but in this case we should print it as "$m[1]" which is not so good for readability)
// - There can be any characters between the date and search word, but it should not contain another date (to solve this we are using negative lookahead "(?:(?!{$date_rgxp}).)+" instead of ".*")
// - Use the "si" modifiers to perform a case-insensitive multi-line search
if (preg_match("#(?P<date>{$date_rgxp})(?:(?!{$date_rgxp}).)+{$search}#si", $subject, $m)) {
    echo $m['date'];
}
```

Comment: Im very thankfull for your help, but could you explain a little more what all this code does?:P

Comment: @J.Doe1989 You are welcome! Check my update for explanation and let me know if you have any questions. By the way, Ray is right — as a rule, you need to vote and accept good answers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code, that I've tested with three cases:

1. Case 1, the date in the front, which you already did.
2. Case 2, the date in the end, I just did small modification to the first one.
3. Case 3, the date is in new line, which explained below.

`preg_match_all` has a flag called `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` which will return the offset of the captured pattern, then the same function has offset parameter that can be set, so what I did is, I searched for the pattern for case 1 and 2, if not found, then search the pattern with the `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE`, then do a second search, this time use the output of the `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` flag as offset, and return the date that is the only in the line.

Hope this solution helps you.

```
<?php

    $subject = "22/10/2013 ånger, ska bet 6,428:-, 
    bet 6428, 2109+2016+2303 inlagt
    23/5/2014 bl 26/5, medd inga avgifter) 
     spelmissbruk 
     29/7/2014
    29/12/2014 föreslår godkänn
    27/4/2016 Föreslår godkänn
    CUSTOM TESTx 27/12/2018
    27/12/2018 - CUSTOM TEST 
    TESTVAL
    05/12/1987";
    $pattern = '- CUSTOM';
    $search = TRUE;

        /*Make sure you are searching a valid pattern*/
        if(!preg_match_all("/.*$pattern.*/",$subject, $matches)){
            echo "NO PATTERN MATCH";

        }
        /*Search the case that the date infront of the text*/
        if(preg_match_all("/(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}).*$pattern.*/i",$subject, $matches))  {
            $date = $matches[0][0][0];

        }
        /*Search the case that the date is after the text*/
        if(preg_match_all("/.*$pattern.*(\d{1,2}.\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4})/",$subject, $matches))  {
            //echo "MATCH LAST";
            $date = $matches[0][0][0];
        }
        if(preg_match_all("/.*$pattern.*/",$subject, $matches,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE )){
            //echo " CAPTURED OFFSET ".$matches[0][0][1];
            if(preg_match_all("/(\d{1,2}.\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4})/",$subject, $dateMatches,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE,$matches[0][0][1]))  {
                //echo " CAPTURED OFFSET DATE";
                $date = $dateMatches[0][0][0];
            }

        }

    if(isset($date)){
        echo $date;
    }



    ?>
```

Comment: Wowsa! Thank you for a awsome answer!

Comment: you have to choose one as accepted answer @J.Doe1989 :)